# Returning an array address from a function to a pointer (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

My homework assignment is quoted below. In case I misread something.

> "In a file called PointerPractice.cpp, write a function called concatArrays that takes two int arrays
>   as arguments and concatenates the two arrays into a third larger array that the function creates.
>   The function should use only pointer arithmetic (no array notation) and should return a pointer to
>   the newly created array.  The function should have the following prototype:
>      int* concatArray(int* pArray1, int size1, int* pArray2, int size2).
>
> In your main function:
>
> 1. Create two int arrays of size 8 and 10.
> 2. Using loops, fill both arrays with random numbers.  Each random number should be in
>      the range 0 to 9 (inclusive).
> 3. Print both arrays with some annotation indicating which array is being printed.
> 4. Now call concatArray with the two random arrays and their sizes as arguments.
> 5. Using a pointer, save a reference to the returned array from concatArray.
> 6. Finally, print the returned array with some annotation indicating that it’s the resulting array
>      from concatArray."

When I print from the function itself, it prints out correctly. When I try to print it out in main, it prints out random strings of numbers per address, not a single number from 0-9.

The function:

```
int* concatArray(int* pArray1, int size1, int* pArray2, int size2)
{
    int newArray[size1+size2];

    for(int i=0; i<size1+size2; i++)
    {
        if(i>size1)
        {
            *(newArray+i) = *(pArray2+i-size1);
        }

        else
        {
            *(newArray+i) = *(pArray1+i);
        }
    }

    cout<<endl;

    for(int i=0; i<size1+size2; i++)
    {
        cout << *(newArray+i)<<endl;
    }

    return newArray;
```

Where I called function in main:

```
ptrConcatArray = concatArray(myArray1, size1, myArray2, size2);

    cout <<endl;
    cout << "Resultant array:" << endl;

    for(int i=0; i<size1; i++)
    {
        cout << *(ptrConcatArray+i)<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: you cannot declare a variable in a function and then return it by value to the caller, but you can either return a copy of it or an address to a memory space that is non-local like a heap object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning a pointer to a local array. The array has been destroyed by the time the function returns, leaving the pointer dangling (that is, not pointing to anything valid).

You should return `std::vector<int>`, a dynamic array which is correctly copyable (unlike the built-in array types), and manages the array's memory automatically.

If your assignment forbids using the standard library (as it seems to when it says "using a pointer"), then perhaps you could return a pointer to an array allocated with `new`:

```
int * newArray = new int[size1+size2];
```

This is a bad idea, since it places the onus on the caller to delete the array once it's finished with; but the worst that can happen is a memory leak, not the memory corruption and undefined behaviour you'd get by returning a dangling pointer.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's what I think my professor wants me to do. Forgot about the new operator.

Answer (score 0):

`int newArray[size1+size2];` is local variable, it can not be a return value.

`int newArray = new int[size1+size2];` should be ok.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Helped me figure out the solution.